# Webex Constantly Crashing on Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11, cisco-webex

I use webex for work and recently is started crashing and I need to understand why this is the case.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start Webex
2. Login with email and password
3. Join a meeting

Results:

The meeting window opens and I see other participants but immediately closes. The participants see me on their end but I don't have the meeting window open at my end and can neither be reached by them or hear them.

In my Webex window under meetings I see the "meeting" I previously tried to join but I can't open a window to that meeting.

Steps already taken:

1. Use the `CiscoWebexRemoveTool' to remove all files of webex
2. Uninstall webex
3. Restart my system
4. Reinstall webex

Used the window debub tool but unfortunately I can properly interpret the results. I need a more experienced pro to help me analyze the result so I can fix this issue.

```
************* Preparing the environment for Debugger Extensions Gallery repositories **************
   ExtensionRepository : Implicit
   UseExperimentalFeatureForNugetShare : false
   AllowNugetExeUpdate : false
   AllowNugetMSCredentialProviderInstall : false
   AllowParallelInitializationOfLocalRepositories : true

   -- Configuring repositories
      ----> Repository : LocalInstalled, Enabled: true
      ----> Repository : UserExtensions, Enabled: true

>>>>>>>>>>>>> Preparing the environment for Debugger Extensions Gallery repositories completed, duration 0.000 seconds

************* Waiting for Debugger Extensions Gallery to Initialize **************

>>>>>>>>>>>>> Waiting for Debugger Extensions Gallery to Initialize completed, duration 0.016 seconds
   ----> Repository : UserExtensions, Enabled: true, Packages count: 0
   ----> Repository : LocalInstalled, Enabled: true, Packages count: 36

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.25877.1004 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Users\ekojo\Documents\crash.dmp]
User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available


************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Version 22621 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS
Edition build lab: 22621.1.amd64fre.ni_release.220506-1250
Debug session time: Wed Jul  5 14:51:16.000 2023 (UTC + 1:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 1:34:13.366
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:23:00.000
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
...........................................
Loading unloaded module list
.............................
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(4938.5688): Wake debugger - code 80000007 (first/second chance not available)

+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| This target supports Hardware-enforced Stack Protection. A HW based    |
| "Shadow Stack" may be available to assist in debugging and analysis.   |
| See aka.ms/userhsp for more info.                                      |
|                                                                        |
| dps @ssp                                                               |
|                                                                        |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+

For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
KERNELBASE!RaiseFailFastException+0x152:
00007ffc`a39fb832 0f1f440000      nop     dword ptr [rax+rax]
0:000> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 1624

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 35968

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Other.Mb
    Value: 21

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Read.Mb
    Value: 0

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Write.Mb
    Value: 24

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 218

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 41263

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 206

    Key  : Failure.Bucket
    Value: APPLICATION_HANG_BusyHang_80000007_twinapi.appcore.dll!wil::details::WilDynamicLoadRaiseFailFastException

    Key  : Failure.Hash
    Value: {0c803e8f-defd-2493-fef4-7f5a848c9aa1}

    Key  : Timeline.OS.Boot.DeltaSec
    Value: 5653

    Key  : Timeline.Process.Start.DeltaSec
    Value: 1380

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: ni_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.22621.1

    Key  : WER.Process.Version
    Value: 1.0.0.2


FILE_IN_CAB:  crash.dmp

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

PROCESS_BAM_CURRENT_THROTTLED: 0

PROCESS_BAM_PREVIOUS_THROTTLED: 0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
rax=000000f9e5987770 rbx=000000f9e5987cf0 rcx=000000f9e5987770
rdx=000000f9e5987c20 rsi=000000f9e5987cf0 rdi=000000f9e5987770
rip=00007ffca39fb832 rsp=000000f9e5987690 rbp=0000000000000001
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=000000f9e5987be0 r10=ab9c9e1158d98970
r11=000000f9e5987930 r12=0000000000000001 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=00007ffc9b71c38f
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000204
KERNELBASE!RaiseFailFastException+0x152:
00007ffc`a39fb832 0f1f440000      nop     dword ptr [rax+rax]
Resetting default scope

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000000000000
   ExceptionCode: 80000007 (Wake debugger)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

PROCESS_NAME:  CiscoCollabHost.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000007 - {Kernel Debugger Awakened}  the system debugger was awakened by an interrupt.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  80000007

DERIVED_WAIT_CHAIN:  

Dl Eid Cid     WaitType
-- --- ------- --------------------------
   0   4938.5688 Unknown                

WAIT_CHAIN_COMMAND:  ~0s;k;;

BLOCKING_THREAD:  0000000000005688

FAULTING_THREAD:  00005688

STACK_TEXT:  
000000f9`e5987690 00007ffc`9b61d46f     : 000000f9`e5987ea0 00007ffc`a39fb6e0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000002 : KERNELBASE!RaiseFailFastException+0x152
000000f9`e5987c70 00007ffc`9b61d56e     : 000000f9`e5987dc0 00000000`00000046 000002dc`cf907818 000002dc`bc108a88 : twinapi_appcore!wil::details::WilDynamicLoadRaiseFailFastException+0x5f
000000f9`e5987ca0 00007ffc`9b61d544     : 000000f9`e5987dc0 00007ffc`80040111 000002dc`d531d408 00000000`00000000 : twinapi_appcore!wil::details::WilRaiseFailFastException+0x22
000000f9`e5987cd0 00007ffc`9b6179db     : 00000000`0000014e 000000f9`e5989360 000002dc`adde8a10 000000f9`e5987e00 : twinapi_appcore!wil::details::WilFailFast+0xbc
000000f9`e5987da0 00007ffc`9b61754c     : 00007ffc`9b763458 00007ffc`9b76345c 00000000`00000010 000002dc`d986fe40 : twinapi_appcore!wil::details::ReportFailure_NoReturn<3>+0x2df
000000f9`e59892a0 00007ffc`9b6176f3     : 00000000`00000000 00007ffc`a007d206 000002dc`d1e3e1a0 00000000`00000001 : twinapi_appcore!wil::details::ReportFailure_Base<3,0>+0x30
000000f9`e5989300 00007ffc`9b619f5b     : 000000f9`e5980000 000002dc`d9f615e0 000002dc`d986fd48 00007ffc`9b5a4e62 : twinapi_appcore!wil::details::ReportFailure_Hr<3>+0x5f
000000f9`e5989380 00007ffc`9b71c38f     : 000002dc`d9f615e0 00007ffc`9b71cbc0 000000f9`e5989420 000002dc`d9f615f0 : twinapi_appcore!wil::details::in1diag3::FailFast_Unexpected+0x1b
000000f9`e59893d0 00007ffc`9b71c4cc     : 000000f9`e5989420 000002dc`d9f615e0 000002dc`d986fe38 000002dc`d9f615f0 : twinapi_appcore!Windows::Internal::Shell::ShareWindow::Bamo::ShareWindowCommandBamoClientConnection::SetBootstrapProxy+0x4f
000000f9`e5989400 00007ffc`9b71c2e9     : 00007ffc`9b71c490 00000000`00000028 000002dc`d9d8cd88 00000000`00000002 : twinapi_appcore!ShareWindowCommandBamos_AutoBamos::BamoConnection::SetBootstrapProxyCallout+0x3c
000000f9`e5989450 00007ffc`a00742b0     : 000002dc`d9d8cd88 00000000`00000002 000002dc`d986fd48 00000000`00000000 : twinapi_appcore!Microsoft::BamoImpl::BaseBamoConnectionImpl::SetBootstrapProxy+0xa9
000000f9`e5989480 00007ffc`9b71aa72     : 00000000`00000000 00007ffc`00000000 000000f9`e5989720 00007ffc`9b5b23f5 : CoreMessaging!CoreUICallReceive+0xa0
000000f9`e5989690 00007ffc`9b71a9f7     : 00000000`00000000 000002dc`d1f5e6b0 00007ffc`9b71a990 00007ffb`e3cc5340 : twinapi_appcore!BamoImpl::ShareWindowCommandBamos_AutoBamos::BamoPeerImpl::OnMessage+0x42
000000f9`e59896e0 00007ffc`a007f8bc     : 000002dc`d1f5e6a0 000000f9`e59897a0 00000000`00000000 00007ffc`a012500c : twinapi_appcore!Microsoft::BamoImpl::ConnectionIndirector::OnItemMessage+0x67
000000f9`e5989720 00007ffc`a007f2cc     : 000002dc`aeff0c00 000002dc`aeff0c00 000002dc`aeff0c00 00007ffc`9b71a990 : CoreMessaging!CFlat::SehSafe::Execute<<lambda_de6cc8128f8f9f99144226758963eeb9> >+0x5c
000000f9`e5989770 00007ffc`a007f4ba     : 000002dc`d9a637b0 000002dc`aac42e80 000000f9`00000002 00007ffb`80200001 : CoreMessaging!Microsoft::CoreUI::ICallbackMessageConversationHost::Interface$::ImportDispatcher::OnItemMessage+0x12c
000000f9`e5989800 00007ffc`a007def7     : 00000000`00000001 000002dc`d98b6520 000000f9`e5989918 000002dc`d55ecc00 : CoreMessaging!Microsoft::CoreUI::ICallbackMessageConversationHost::Interface$::StaticDispatcher::OnItemMessage+0x16a
000000f9`e59898c0 00007ffc`a008a35e     : 000002dc`d1d28c30 000002dc`d9d8cd88 000002dc`d9a637b0 000002dc`d98b6520 : CoreMessaging!Microsoft::CoreUI::Conversations::ItemMessageDispatcher::Callback_OnMessageCore+0xf7
000000f9`e5989950 00007ffc`a008a045     : 000002dc`aeff0e40 000002dc`d5f79101 00000000`00000043 000000f9`e5989ab0 : CoreMessaging!Microsoft::CoreUI::Messaging::MessageSession::Callback_DeliverMessage+0x2be
000000f9`e5989a50 00007ffc`a0089e4e     : 00000000`00000000 000002dc`d1e3ef60 00000000`00000043 000000f9`e5989b90 : CoreMessaging!Microsoft::CoreUI::Messaging::MessageSession::Callback_DeliverMessageBatch+0x125
000000f9`e5989b10 00007ffc`a0089c6b     : 000002dc`aac40000 00000000`00000000 000002dc`d1d29878 00000000`00000008 : CoreMessaging!Microsoft::CoreUI::Messaging::AlpcClientSender::Callback_ProcessBuffer+0x1ce
000000f9`e5989be0 00007ffc`a008e27e     : 000002dc`aac40000 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000200 00000000`00000000 : CoreMessaging!Microsoft::CoreUI::Messaging::AlpcClientThunk::Callback_ProcessAsynchronousBuffer+0x1b
000000f9`e5989c20 00007ffc`a008efd7     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00007ffc`a35b34f0 000002dc`d55ecb90 : CoreMessaging!AlpcConnection::Callback_DeliverBatchedBuffers+0x7e
000000f9`e5989c80 00007ffc`a008e98a     : 00000000`00000000 000000f9`e5989e80 000000f9`e5989df9 000000f9`e5989df0 : CoreMessaging!AlpcConnection::HandleSubsequentBufferInBatch+0xf3
000000f9`e5989cd0 00007ffc`a008e56d     : 00000000`00000068 00000000`00000000 000000f9`e5989df9 000002dc`d5f78260 : CoreMessaging!AlpcConnection::Callback_HandleReceivedBuffer+0x26a
000000f9`e5989d80 00007ffc`a0084878     : 000002dc`bb4dad01 000000f9`e5989e80 000000f9`e5989eb0 00007ffc`a00b3b00 : CoreMessaging!AlpcConnection::Callback_ProcessIncoming+0x26d
000000f9`e5989e60 00007ffc`a0085b0c     : 000002dc`d5f78201 000002dc`aeff0e40 000002dc`d5f77240 00007ffc`a00b9275 : CoreMessaging!`CFlat::DelegateImpl<System::Action,0,void __cdecl(void),void,0>::Bind<CFlat::SmartPtr<Microsoft::CoreUI::Messaging::AlpcClientSender>,&Microsoft::CoreUI::Messaging::AlpcClientSender::Callback_OnReceive>'::`2'::Thunk::Invoke+0x48
000000f9`e5989eb0 00007ffc`a00823ef     : 000002dc`bb689020 000002dc`d9e54de0 000002dc`bb6eddb8 00000000`00000000 : CoreMessaging!Microsoft::CoreUI::Dispatch::OffThreadReceiver::Callback_OnDispatch+0x1bc
000000f9`e5989f50 00007ffc`a0080033     : 000002dc`aef022f0 000002dc`aef025c0 000002dc`aeff0e40 000002dc`aeff0e40 : CoreMessaging!Microsoft::CoreUI::Dispatch::EventLoop::Callback_RunCoreLoop+0x36f
000000f9`e598a060 00007ffc`a007fbf6     : 000002dc`bb4d5ba0 000002dc`bb6f0960 000002dc`00000004 00000000`00000000 : CoreMessaging!Microsoft::CoreUI::Dispatch::UserAdapter::OnUserDispatch+0x1f3
000000f9`e598a0f0 00007ffc`a007d0ac     : 00000000`00110c76 00007ffb`00000004 00000009`fa52e601 000002dc`aeeff4b0 : CoreMessaging!Microsoft::CoreUI::Dispatch::UserAdapter::DoWork+0x206
000000f9`e598a180 00007ffc`a3ee8211     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`80000022 : CoreMessaging!Microsoft::CoreUI::Dispatch::UserAdapter::WindowProc+0x14c
000000f9`e598a1f0 00007ffc`a3ee7ecc     : 00000000`00000388 00007ffc`a007cf60 00000000`00110c76 00000000`80000000 : user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x2d1
000000f9`e598a350 00007ffc`a3ef2ffd     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00007ffc`a3f62000 : user32!DispatchClientMessage+0x9c
000000f9`e598a3b0 00007ffc`a6192d94     : 00007ffc`a35714d4 000002dc`ae800a00 00000000`00000000 000000f9`e598a498 : user32!_fnDWORD+0x3d
000000f9`e598a410 00007ffc`a35714d4     : 00007ffc`a3ef1b1f 000000f9`e598a490 ffffffff`ffffff01 ffffffff`ffffffff : ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcherContinue
000000f9`e598a498 00007ffc`a3ef1b1f     : 000000f9`e598a490 ffffffff`ffffff01 ffffffff`ffffffff 00007ffc`a3ee8067 : win32u!NtUserPeekMessage+0x14
000000f9`e598a4a0 00007ffc`a3ef19ec     : 00000000`00000001 000000f9`e5a1b800 00000000`00000000 00007ffb`ca7d1040 : user32!_PeekMessage+0x3f
000000f9`e598a510 00007ffb`ea8b274c     : 00000000`00000024 000000f9`e598a680 000002dc`ae203c98 00000000`00000002 : user32!PeekMessageW+0x9c
000000f9`e598a580 00007ffb`d57f3229     : 000002dc`ae39b580 00000000`00000000 000000f9`e598d701 000002dc`00000000 : Qt5Core!QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents+0x35c
000000f9`e598d6c0 00007ffb`ea85caf4     : 00000000`00000024 00000000`00000014 00000000`00000000 000002dc`ae74c690 : qwindows!qt_plugin_instance+0x20b9
000000f9`e598d6f0 00007ffb`ea85fbdc     : 000002dc`adba14e8 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00007ffb`ea99db30 : Qt5Core!QEventLoop::exec+0x244
000000f9`e598d780 00007ffb`c95b30ac     : 000002dc`ae20e510 00000000`00000000 000002dc`ae20e520 000002dc`ae7166a0 : Qt5Core!QCoreApplication::exec+0x15c
000000f9`e598d7e0 00007ffb`c89588e8     : 00000000`0000000f 00000000`0000000f 00000000`00000000 000000f9`e598f288 : spark_windows_desktop_ui!ApplicationRunner::runApplication+0xc4c
000000f9`e598e090 00007ffc`7018108c     : 00000000`00000005 000002dc`aaddde01 00000000`0000000a 00000000`00000005 : spark_windows_desktop_ui!Main::sparkWindowsDesktopMain+0x2f68
000000f9`e598f590 00007ffc`57c32136     : 00000000`0000006c 00007ffc`70181020 00000000`0000006c 00000000`0000000a : spark_windows_app_impl!SparkEntryPointImpl+0x6c
000000f9`e598f800 00007ff7`43f51ddf     : 00007ffc`57c31b20 000002dc`aadf6140 000002dc`aaddde60 00007ffc`57c30000 : spark_windows_app!SparkEntryPoint+0x616
000000f9`e598f870 00007ffc`a54826ad     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : CiscoCollabHost+0x1ddf
000000f9`e598f910 00007ffc`a614aa68     : 00000000`00000800 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x1d
000000f9`e598f940 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x28


STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s ; .cxr ; kb

SYMBOL_NAME:  twinapi_appcore!wil::details::WilDynamicLoadRaiseFailFastException+5f

MODULE_NAME: twinapi_appcore

IMAGE_NAME:  twinapi.appcore.dll

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_HANG_BusyHang_80000007_twinapi.appcore.dll!wil::details::WilDynamicLoadRaiseFailFastException

OS_VERSION:  10.0.22621.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  ni_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.22621.1928

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {0c803e8f-defd-2493-fef4-7f5a848c9aa1}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: Consider doing a Windows 11 Repair Install. Uninstall Webex, Repair Install, Reinstall Webex.

Comment: Please can you point out the issue here, reinstall might not be an option for now

Comment: Repair Install is a repair not a reinstall.   Repair and Keep Everything.

Comment: Could you upload the file `C:\Users\ekojo\Documents\crash.dmp` for us to have a look? Use any online service such as OneDrive. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Something is wrong with this file. Could you zip it up?

Comment: @harrymc https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtI96fPD5M3M1C86Lj_l8vH1-Xrr?e=cPz8zd I made it view only

Comment: I can see that the crash happened inside a Windows component called `twinapi.appcore.dll`. Are Windows and Webex fully updated? Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc unfortunately the same still happens

Comment: There were no messages by DISM or SFC?

Comment: DISM said nothing but SFC found corrupt files and fixed it

Comment: SFC is not a good fixer. The fact that it found anything means a corruption in Windows. You need to do [Repair Install](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/) to return Windows to a consistent state while keeping all apps and settings. This is the same as doing a major Windows upgrade, so take the same precautions.

Comment: @harrymc same results after repair install

Comment: You should address yourself to Webex Support. I don't see what else you can do beside reinstalling Webex and updating everything.